# Force refresh cache on js/css/html changes webapp

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, browser-cache

I need the browser to get changes instead of the cached ones after doing any javascript, css, or HTML changes.
Giving scripts versions (ex: script.css?v=1.0) is not working on Firefox, and working on chrome though.
What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You need to set your response headers to disable caching or cache but re-validate before serving those static assets again. Have a look at this [link](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) to know more about different cache headers

Comment: Thanks this helped me understand a lot of thing, but I used this [article](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I was using IIS, and I added a cache-control header as described [here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1190209.aspx).